# .whl is not a valid wheel filename, storing debug log for failure in C:\

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I am having trouble installing a wheel file via pip.

1. I open my command prompt
2. write the following in the prompt

   `C:/Python34/Scripts/pip install C:/Users/Hamsa/Downloads/pygame.whl`
3. Then I get this message

   `pygame.whl is not a valid wheel filename. Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Hamsa\pip\pip.log`

I don't what to do and I need your help.

Comment: So what you have in log file?

Comment: I know `pip` isn't the full filename for that - have you tried using the full, exact filenames for everything?

Comment: what does `import pip; print(pip.pep425tags.get_supported())` give?

Comment: This is some of what I have in the text document: C:\Python34\Scripts\pip run on 10/19/15 13:49:11
pygame.whl is not a valid wheel filename...

Comment: Did you change the original name of the .whl file? If you did then it won't work, use the original name and try it

Comment: import pip... gives I long error message.

Comment: If I use the original name I get this message "... is not supported wheel on this platform"

Comment: My `.whl` file was a result of `wheel convert some.egg`. I renamed original `.whl` which leads to pip complaining about "not a valid filename". When I use original filename everything works as expected.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should correct name format for installing wheel file. Because wheel file name also includes many information such as the version of program, supported python version. Your command should be like the command below.

```
pip install pygame‑1.9.3‑cp34‑cp34m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: Thank you. converting underscore to dash (except the last one) solved my problem

Answer (score 3):

If the answer suggested by @Harun doesnot work, try

```
python -m pip install <whl file name with complete path>.whl
```

If u have more than 1 Python versions installed , check which version of python is being used to install the package using:

```
python -v
```

Also refer to [pygame readme](http://www.pygame.org/readme.html) for an official installation guide.

Comment: If any of the answers works, kindly upvote and Mark that answer as correct. It will help anyone who faces a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

download `fasttext-0.9.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl` wheel file from [lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#fasttext) and then `cd` download path

```
pip3 install fasttext-0.9.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
```

after that

```
pip install fasttext
```