# Python : couldn't install py2exe using Winpython : not compatible error

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I tried installing py2exe for converting python code to a exe file using WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4.

I downloaded the file **py2exe-0.6.9.win64-py2.7.amd64.exe**

from https://sourceforge.net/projects/py2exe/files/py2exe/0.6.9/

While installing using WinPython Control Panel, it shows an error message as below.

[image]

Comment: For the sake of people doing internet searches, here's the text of the error: "The following packages filenaming are not recognized by WinPython Control Panel: py2exe-0.6.9.win64-py2.7.amd64.exe"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rename it as py2exe-0.6.9.win-amd64.exe, then try again

Comment: After renaming, I got it installed.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it doesn't matter what the file is called, WinPython control panel won't like it. In this case, open up "WinPython Command Prompt.exe" (which is in the same directory as WinPython Control Panel) and run:

```
python -m pip install "name-of-python-package.whl"
```

Note: pip also requires the package filename to be formatted correctly, but if you have the latest version of pip and the latest python package, you should be fine.

This question is also related: [.whl is not a valid wheel filename, storing debug log for failure in C:\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33213430/whl-is-not-a-valid-wheel-filename-storing-debug-log-for-failure-in-c)